# Laravel 5.2 Vue.js computed doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, vue.js, vue-resource

How can I show objects returned by vue?
The provinces are Ok, But cities v-for doesn't work.

This is My Blade :

```
<select v-model="ProvinceModel" name="province" id="province" class="border-radius-0 form-control padding-y-0">
    <option v-for="province in provinces" value="@{{ province.id }}"> @{{ province.name }} </option>
</select>

<select name="city" id="city" class="border-radius-0 form-control padding-y-0">
    <option v-for="city in cities" value="@{{ city.id }}"> @{{ city.name }} </option>
</select>
```

This is my scripts

```
new Vue({
        el: '#vue',
        methods: {
            fetchProvinces: function () {
                this.$http.get('{{url('api/provinces')}}').then(function (provinces) {
                    this.$set('provinces', provinces.data)
                });
            }

        },
        computed: {
            cities() {
                this.$http.get("{{url('api/cities')}}/" + this.ProvinceModel).then(function (cities) {
                    console.log(cities.data);
                    this.$set('cities', cities.data)
                });

            }
        },
        ready: function () {
            this.fetchProvinces()
        },
    });
```

And route

```
Route::get('cities/{provinces_id}', function ($id = 8) {
    return \App\province::find($id)->cities()->get();
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: You're not using `select2` (https://select2.github.io/), as far as I can tell from your question. If you are, update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @ceejayoz I just need my problem is resolved, If you can help me men .

Comment: I'm trying to help you. Read my answer. I've given you the information you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed functions should return something, and sycnchronously. You're not returning anything.

You're also attempting to set `this.cities` as data, but `this.cities` is already a computed function. One's gonna override the other and cause inconsistent/confusing behavior.

Fetching cities asynchronously should be a method, just like your `fetchProvinces` method. You should fetch them when `ProvinceModel` is changed, which you can probably do via a `@change` event on the selector, or a Vue watcher on the value of `ProvinceModel`.

<sup>Side note: Generally, it's best to define your data items in the component's `data` parameter. If you check your JS console, Vue's likely throwing warnings about that.</sup>

Comment: Please read these are .
[Link1](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3165) 
[Link2](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-validator/issues/273) 
[Link3](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2064)

Comment: @MortezaNegahi None of those appear at all relevant to your situation.

Comment: But in vue document @change doesn't exist ! and vue author said this event Perhaps goes down!

Comment: @MortezaNegahi I believe you can use `v-on` with `change`, or use the `watch` approach to observe the value of the province. Please read the entire answer.

Answer (score 0):

Vuejs not flexible, you can get value through jquery, pass it to control. Element by ref method is good.

Vuejs  can not wait for worker,when it get busy, so naturally variable when it is not in value show undefined.

Comment: "Vuejs not flexible" What?

Comment: At first before giving a negative rating, discover what is written!
  When Veujs for chnage event of element did not anticipate anything no not flexible! We do not work with static pages. Our pages dynamic!

Comment: @muhamadzolfaghari I'm still entirely unclear about what you're trying to say. Vue.js is very flexible, and it's entirely possible to have two select boxes interact with each other. What OP wants to do is entirely doable within Vue - there's no need for jQuery.